# Use span instead of label in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Using :

```
 <%= f.label :registration,"Registration" %>
```

Will create a label:

`<label for="cad_registration">Registration</label>`

I want it to be a span like this one :

`<span for="cad_registration">Registration</span>`

Comment: then dont to `f.label`, write a span instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<span>` element does not support the `for`-attribute. So, using a `<span>`-element instead of the `<label>` does not make sense.

Why do you not use (CSS) styles to style the `<label>` into the desired result?
Use the `id`-attribute if you only want to style this particular element.

For example to make the label text red, using something like this:

ERB:

```
<%= f.label :registration,"Registration", :html => { :id => "my-label" } %>
```

CSS:

```
#my-label {
    text-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think i need to ask my designer to use a label and not a span :).

Comment: If you need a `label` `for` a form field: yes! :)

Answer (score 2):

You're not creating a label then, you shouldn't use the `label` helper. The `for` attribute doesn't exist on `<span>` elements.

Replace your code with the bottom line you wrote but without the `for`:

```
<span>Registration</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom form builder to modify how form labels are output to your requirements. There's a brief overview here - http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/form-builders-in-rails.html. There is also a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/311-form-builders) on this topic which is more thorough but it's a pro (paid) episode.

Comment: It is not allowed to have a `<span>`-element that contains a `for`-attribute. So creating a custom form builder does not solve the problem...

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with the following solution, extending the rails FormBuilder

in your application helper

```
module ApplicationHelper
  class TestFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
        include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper

        def span(name, options = {})
          css_classes = []
          css_classes = options[:class].to_s if options[:class]
          content_tag('span', name, :class => css_classes.join(' '))
        end
  end
end
```

and in your view you could use

```
<%= form_for @<module>, :builder => ApplicationHelper::TestFormBuilder do |f| %>
  #your code 
  <%= f.span(:name) %>
<% end %>
```

this works and thanks for the question, which made me to think extending FormBuilder ;),

and these links helped me [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276456/how-to-correctly-extend-form-for-actionviewhelpersformbuilder), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633493/nested-content-tag-throws-undefined-method-output-buffer-in-simple-helper), and you might want to do some more modifications

HTH

Comment: Thanks very much  for your time and answer .. I will check that.It's a nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

just write down the span outside the ruby

```
<span for=<%= :registration %>><%="Registration"%></span>
```

Comment: It is not allowed to have a `<span>`-element that contains a `for`-attribute. So creating a custom form builder does not solve the problem...